# Getting the name of a method used as a block in Ruby

Tags: ruby

If a method is called in a block, how do I get it's name? For example, I have this simple logger (adapted from Ross Olsen's book *Eloquent Ruby*):

```
def self.with_logging(text, &block)
  begin
    puts ">> START:  #{text}"
    yield if block_given?
    puts "<< END:    #{text}"
  rescue
    puts "-- FAILED: #{text}"
    raise
  end
end
```

and I use it to log calls to method `foo` like this:

```
with_logging('foo') { foo }
```

The method name `foo` is repeated in both the text parameter and the block for `with_logging`. I'd like to remove this duplication, making the `text` parameter default to the name of the method used in the block, but how would I find the method's name?

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to do that unless with meta-programming that looks into the parsed result of the code.

But you can do the other way around. Given the name of the method and absence of a block, you can make it call that method in the block by default.

```
def self.with_logging(text)
  begin
    puts ">> START:  #{text}"
    block_given? yield : send(text)
    puts "<< END:    #{text}"
  rescue
    puts "-- FAILED: #{text}"
    raise
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks @sawa. But unfortunately I sometimes I want to add text that's different from the name of the method...